# How can I reset to Ubuntu Studio default desktop and settings?

Tags: settings, default, reset

After some issues and an upgrade I have a very different appearance in my Ubuntu Studio. I just want to reset to the defaults just like if the installation is brand new.

Answer (score 0):

If the changes is in desktop only you may reinstall the desktop like this:

```bsh
sudo apt reinstall ubuntustudio-desktop-core ubuntustudio-desktop
```

> note: this won't change all configrations if you changed something not related to desktop itself

or you better go back throw your customizations and reverse it